# Can't boot Lubuntu 64-bit without UEFI-CSM support

Tags: boot, lubuntu, uefi, csm

I have a thin client Wyse D90D7. It can't boot Lubuntu and any other linux distro 64-bit that doesn't have UEFI-CSM. it always get stuck on black screen without error. Installing 32-bit is not an option because some softwares I use no longer support 32-bit and the hardware is based on 64-bit. Linux Lite 64-bit with CSM support and Windows 10 x64 boots perfect but it's running slow so I prefer Lubuntu on thin client.

I used Rufus and it does tell if ISO have UEFI-CSM or UEFI only

Is it possible to add CSM support on bootable USB?

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me - if you want to run a 64bit operating system, you should not need the CSM at all. Did you have the chance to set the boot mode? Using `UEFI` should work fine without the CSM, just the `legacy` mode might trigger the CSM and this in turn might conflict with `Secure Boot`, which is somewhat likely to be activated if your're running Win10. You could turn off `Secure Boot` to circumvent this, but I don't know how Win10 reacts on this, so try to make sure first you're running the installer in `UEFI` mode,  and then the problem might be solved already.

Comment: The BIOS doesn't have Secure boot option and it only have very very few options unlike normal PCs. I'm not sure how to run it in UEFI mode.

Answer (score 3):

By making two changes in how I burn the image using Rufus, I am able to get a USB installer that works on a Wyse D90D7:

1. Check the "Add Fixes for old BIOSes" option in the Advanced Drive Properties area
2. When you click the Start button to burn the image, it will ask if you want the recommended write method, or DD.  Choose DD.